# Android Unparseable date: "2017-12-01 00:00:00+01"

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat, timezone-offset

I am trying to parse the date-time string `2017-12-01 00:00:00+01`.
My pattern is as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
```

The exception “Unparseable date: "2017-12-01 00:00:00+01"” is thrown with Android 7 and above.

I found another pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX" but it works only with Android 7 and above.

I tried this workaround "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZZZ" that I found here, but it doesn't work.

Is there a solution that will also work with Android below Android 7?

Comment: Try using a different library. http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/

Comment: That is not a valid format supported by [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) on API < 24. Do take a look at [RFC 822 time zone format](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) and [ISO 8601 time zone format](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone).

Answer (score 1):

I will give you the good solution and the hack.

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX");
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This prints

```
2017-12-01T00:00+01:00
```

This is the good solution: `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. There are at least two reasons why you would want to do this on Android.

1. The `SimpleDateFormat` class that you have been using is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome, so I would recommend you don’t use it anyway, and the modern API is so much nicer to work with.
2. Your time zone offset of `+01` is an ISO 8601 offset. While only later vertsions of `SimpleDateFormat` can parse this, `java.time` has excelled at the ISO 8601 standard from when it came out, so this is a safe bet.

I should say you have a nice opportunity for going future-proof.

Your time of day of `00:00:00` seems to suggest you’re only interested in the date? If so, `java.time` has one more good offer for you, the `LocalDate` class represents a date without time of day:

```
    LocalDate date = dateTime.toLocalDate();
```

This gives a `LocalDate` of 2017-12-01.

### The hack

You may just append minutes of offset of `00` to your string, and the formatter in your question will parse it:

```
    dateTimeString += "00";
```

### Question: how do I use `java.time` on older Android?

If `java.time` is not built-in on your Android device, you get ThreeTenABP and add it to your project, and then import `org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime`, `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate` and `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`. See the links below. The code is unchanged from above.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where the modern date and time API was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `"+01"` time zone suffix. This is not a valid representation of a time zone under either the "[General time zone](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone)" rules or the "[RFC 822 time zone](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone)" rules.

You can change your `SimpleDateFormat` to `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, which will allow the date to be parsed but will ignore the time zone suffix. Then you can manually parse the time zone suffix and modify your `Date` accordingly.

Alternatively, if you can somehow change your input to include offset *minutes* in addition to hours (i.e. change the time zone suffix to `"+0100"`), then your existing date format will work just fine. Including minutes in addition to hours makes the time zone suffix parseable according to RFC 822.